# Can a java file be made an executable?

Tags: java, xml, exe

I was asked to create a  java file , a build.xml file and keep it in the same folder. When i tried to send the folder using Gmail, it showed you're trying to send an executable file !! Why it is considered to be executable when java and xml files are kept together?

Comment: its probably a security feature of GMail. Try password protecting your zip file, that should bypass Gmail's security probe.

Comment: Dunno, ask Google.  They're the ones saying that it's executable.  But why not just zip the two files, and then send the archive?

Comment: Rename .xml and .java files to .txt and zip it and send. If you just keep .xml inside zip also, Gmail won't allow it. But Google forums is the best place to ask this question

Comment: *"a java file"* DYM a file of type `.java`, `.class`, `.jar` or something else again?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [common](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/i2s1fo80VaU)(1) [bug](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/not%2420executable%2420file%2420executable/gmail/AfhXTIMWoww/915lXQlOUMYJ)(2) [around](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/not%2420executable%2420file%2420executable/gmail/l-4ndhm9N74/PQXfR_CN9hQJ)(3) [Gmail's help forums.](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/lhSDrXHO5aU)(4) Try moving the files to a different directory then attaching again.

Comment: how would moving the files in different directory help?

Comment: It was suggested by someone on the linked forum. I don't know why and nor do they, but it worked for them so I thought it might work here.